# How do I use the .loc method to search i rows ahead?

Tags: python, pandas

In particular the part that I'm having trouble with is this:

```
 df.loc[( (df["Close"] > df[f"{MA*Time} MA"]) & (df["Close"][i+Time] > df[f"{MA*Time} MA"][i+Time]) ), f"Strategy {k} on {Time} Mins"] = "Buy"
```

I haven't initialized the variable i, the idea I was going for was simply to have pandas to simultaneously check that both the close price was higher than the moving average for a particular row, and also check n rows ahead of this to see that this condition still holds, (where n is equal to the Time period being analysed) if it does then it's a buy, else it's a sell.

Full code below:

```
TimePeriods2 = [1440] # other elements will be populated to this list later
MovingAverages = [50] # other elements will be populated to this list later

for Time in TimePeriods2:
    k = 1
    for MA in MovingAverages:
        df.loc[( (df["Close"] > df[f"{MA*Time} MA"]) & (df["Close"][i+Time] > df[f"{MA*Time} MA"][i+Time]) ), f"Strategy {k} on {Time} Mins"] = "Buy"
        k+=1
```

Comment: perhaps shift() will work instead of [i+Time]??

Comment: .shift() is the ideal solution, see the answer that I posted, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: (not using `.loc`)

```
import numpy as np

df['action'] = \
    np.where( \
         (df['close'] > df['close'].rolling(window=14).mean()) & (df['close'].shift(i) > df['close'].shift(i).rolling(window=14).mean()), \
         'buy','hold')
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this with the following code:

```
shifted = pd.DataFrame()

for Time in TimePeriods2:
    for MA in MovingAverages:
        shifted[f"{MA*Time} MA"] = df[f"{MA*Time} MA"]

for Time in TimePeriods2:
    for MA in MovingAverages:
        shifted[f"{MA*Time} MA"] = shifted[f"{MA*Time} MA"].shift(Time)

shifted.columns = [column + " (lagged)" for column in shifted.columns]

df = pd.concat((df, shifted), axis=1)




for Time in TimePeriods2:
    k = 1
    for MA in MovingAverages:
        df.loc[( (df["Close"] > df[f"{MA*Time} MA"]) & (df["Close"] > df[f"{MA*Time} MA (lagged)"]) ), f"Moving Average (not crossover) Strategy {k} on {Time} Mins"] = "Buy"
        k += 1
```